# %! - что это за хэш в perl?

Tags: perl

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper\%!'
```

что это за хэш?

Даже

```
 $!{'ENOENT'} = 2
```

Comment: Принимайте ответы, что ли.

Answer (score 2):

perldoc perlvar

Answer (score 2):

Хэш, у которого ненулевое значения для ключа, соответствующего текущей errno.

```
$!{'ENOENT'} = 2
```

ENOENT — это "No such file or directory".

Правильно вам говорят, [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).